# How to earn reputation on an established stack?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I just want to thumbs up a good answer, but I can't. I can't earn reputation because all conceivable simple questions have been asked and answered!

Is there a way to usefully earn reputation on a mature site for a non expert? Or am I forever to be locked out of giving thumbs up?

Comment: *thumbs up* ... this is not facebook ....

Comment: Vomit 123456789

Comment: No, that won't help. Making good edits would be the easiest, as explained in the duplicates. Good luck!.